# Simplifying a logical expression

Tags: logical-operators

I'm looking for a way to simplify this logical expression:

```
((x == y) and (x > 0 or z > 0))
or
((x != y) and (x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0))
```

All variables are non-negative integers.

I thought about using [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), but my variables aren't boolean, which kind of complicates things.

Then I figured I should probably translate that into a set of boolean variables, for example:

- `a = (x == y)`
- `b = (x > 0)`
- `c = (y > 0)`
- `d = (z > 0)`

But those boolean variables aren't exactly independent of each other.

For example, if `a` is `true`, then `b` must be equal to `c`.

Comment: Would you clarify some more? Your code looks simple and readable to me. What to do you mean to simplify?

Comment: @shoek: I'd like a simpler logic, where one could easily determine if the input is permitted (the expression evaluates to `true`) or not. I feel that it is currently rather cumbersome, and that it can potentially be simplified.

Comment: I also think your way is easier to read and understand. Unless you prefer `((x == y) and (x > 0)) or ((x == y) and (z > 0)) or ((x > 0) and (y > 0) and (z > 0))` which is a simpler form of your expression but I personally find it harder to figure out when which input leads to what.

Comment: If you do refactor it so that you use separate variables for the conditions which are duplicated, then use variable names which describe what you're testing. *Don't* just use `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`. Using yet more short variable names would make it harder to understand. Assuming you like shorter variable names, you could use `xEQy = (x == y)`, `xIsPos = x > 0`, `yIsPos = y >0`, and `zIsPos = z >0`, which gives you equations that are *much* more readable than your `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` variable names: For example: `(xEQy and (xIsPos or zIsPos)) or (!xEQy and (xIsPos and yIsPos and zIsPos))`.

Comment: @Makyen: See my comments to the answer below.

Comment: @goodvibration I read your comments under the answer prior to commenting. I don't feel it matters wrt. the point of my comment. The fact that many examples, including this one, suggest using single letter variable names tends to guide how people think. I feel that thinking is significantly divergent from what's good practice in programming in general. Changing that thinking is beneficial, IMO. Part of getting that thinking to change is showing examples which actually use meaningful, self-documenting variable names, rather than meaningless single letter names.

Comment: @Makyen:What part of "my question is about finding an equivalent logical expression, not about coding it" is not clear??? I'm not looking to implement it in code, I'm looking to find an equivalent logical expression using known methods such as *Karnaugh Map*. Variable names are irrelevant here! In fact, single-letter variables are most likely preferable in this case.

Comment: @goodvibration If you want this evaluated only from outside of a programming context, then the question is off-topic. Stack Overflow is for questions which are "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". A *strictly* straight logic problem which you don't permit to be looked at from a programming perspective is not "unique to software development". Looking at a logic problem and determining how to solve it from within a programming context *is* something that is "unique to software development", and thus is reasonable to be on-topic here.

Comment: @Makyen: I thought about the alternative of posting it on math.stackexchange or something similar. But then I noticed the logical-operators tag here, and the question fits well under it. Also *Karnaugh Map* is a term which fits very well under computer-science questions, and since my question is around that area, I've figured it could be answered here. I'll try the math site as well though, because I see salvation isn't coming here any time soon...

Comment: @goodvibration For what you appear to want, one of the math sites may be more appropriate. If you're willing to have it evaluated from a programming perspective, not a *strictly* logical perspective, then Stack Overflow can be a reasonable place for the question. Changing the representation such that you do have boolean variables and using a Karnaugh Map is a reasonable way to approach the issue, more so in some smaller segments of the programming arena and in electrical engineering. However, doing so isn't necessarily a good choice from a programming perspective (as mentioned multiple times).

Answer (score 1):

I'll rewrite in several ways. But before proceeding, I have to say 2 things.

1. If there are, you must ask your teammates what kind of improvement to make, because they are the reader, reviewer and maintainer of your code. They may want a simplification, but sometimes they just want some more comments in your code.
2. You should read stack overflow Tour, which says "Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers." Cumbersome is your opinion. Someone has another opinion. That's ok.

**Rewrites**

Let me assume the original code like this:

```
def executeNextStepIfPermitted(x, y, z):
  if ((x == y) and (x > 0 or z > 0)) or ((x != y) and (x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0)):
    executeNextStep()
  raise Exception("Not permitted")
```

Option 1: Remove unnecessary `()`

```
def executeNextStepIfPermitted(x, y, z):
  if (x == y and (x > 0 or z > 0)) or (x != y and x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0):
    executeNextStep()
  raise Exception("Not permitted")
```

Option 2: Use `if ... elif` instead of `or`

```
def executeNextStepIfPermitted(x, y, z):
  if x == y and (x > 0 or z > 0):
    executeNextStep()
  elif x != y and x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0:
    executeNextStep()
  raise Exception("Not permitted")
```

Option 3: Use nested `if` instead of `and`

```
def executeNextStepIfPermitted(x, y, z):
  if x == y:
    if x > 0 or z > 0:
      executeNextStep()
  elif x != y:
    if x > 0 and y > 0 and z > 0:
      executeNextStep()
  raise Exception("Not permitted")
```

Option 4: Call `max()`, `min()` (Some says it's not plain.)

```
def executeNextStepIfPermitted(x, y, z):
  if x == y and max(x, z) > 0:
    executeNextStep()
  elif x != y and min(x, y, z) > 0:
    executeNextStep()
  raise Exception("Not permitted")
```

Option 5: Explain in comments

```
def executeNextStepIfPermitted(x, y, z):
  if x == y:
    if max(x, z) > 0:     # either of (x, z) is positive
      executeNextStep()
  elif x != y:
    if min(x, y, z) > 0:  # all of (x, y, z) are positive
      executeNextStep()
  raise Exception("Not permitted")
```

Option 6: Use and name variables in self-explanatory way

```
def executeNextStepIfPermitted(x, y, z):
  eitherOfXzIsPositive = max(x, z) > 0
  allOfXyzArePositive = min(x, y, z) > 0

  if x == y and eitherOfXzIsPositive:
    executeNextStep()
  elif x != y and allOfXyzArePositive:
    executeNextStep()
  raise Exception("Not permitted")
```

Which options you should or should not choose? Are there alternatives? Again, you must ask your teammates.

Comment: Sorry, but my question is about finding an equivalent logical expression, not about coding it, and most certainly not about removing brackets or using different variable names.

Comment: I did not tag it under any specific programming language for a reason.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks for your explanation.How about tagging with math and boolean-algebra? I'll leave here, because I don't understand math, nor what it means to be simple in math terminology. You can forget my comments and answers.